# Get row-,column-averages of matrix from text file

Tags: python, file, text, average

My question is how to get each matrix's average and write it in a new text file.

If contents of text is

```
1 -20 -100 50 60
3 4 -100 -3 
-10 5 45 10 -15\n
```

I want to get result like this without using numpy:

> ```
> 1 -20 -100 50 60  avg : -2
> 3 4 -100 -3 0     avg : -20
> -10 5 45 10 -15   avg : 7
> -2 -4 -52 19 15
> ```

Here is my code:

```
with open('number.txt','r') as file1:
    file2 = open('text2.txt','w')
    line = file1.readlines()
    for i in range(len(line)):
        a = str(line[i])
        a.split()
        b = a.split()
        for j in range(len(b)):
            sum(int(b[0][i]))/len(b)
        for z in range(len(b)):
            sum(int(b[i][0]))/len(b)
```

Comment: So you want to round the output? And you are missing a `0` in the text file?

Comment: No, it seems you are truncating the output. Sure you want that?

Comment: Please see my updated answer

Comment: The second row of your matrix only has 4 entries, the other two have 5. Did you want the row-wise average or the per-element average? They'll differ. @JHBonarius zero-padded the second row to 5 elements.

Comment: @smci just like he shows in his output...

Answer (score 1):

## new: ziperdyzip

It seems you don't want to use NumPy for some reason. Well: this is not using numpy:

```
rowMean = [sum(row)//len(row) for row in data]
colmean = [sum(col)//len(col) for col in list(map(list, zip(*data)))]
```

Complete example:

```
with open('number.txt', 'r') as file1:
    data = file1.readlines()
data = [line.split() for line in data]
data = [list(map(int, row)) for row in data]

outData = [list(map(str, row)) + ['avg :', str(sum(row)//len(row)), '\n'] for row in data]
outData.append([str(sum(col)//len(col)) for col in list(map(list, zip(*data)))])

with open('text2.txt', 'w') as file2:
    file2.writelines([' '.join(row) for row in outData])
```

Or in compact with right justification form:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile, open('number.txt', 'r') as infile:
    data = [list(map(int, line.split())) for line in infile.readlines()]
    outfile.writelines([' '.join([str(el).rjust(4) for el in row] + ['avg :', str(sum(row)//len(row)).rjust(4), '\n']) for row in data])
    outfile.write(' '.join([str(sum(col)//len(col)).rjust(4) for col in list(map(list, zip(*data)))]))
```

output:

```
   1  -20 -100   50   60 avg :   -2 
   3    4 -100   -3    0 avg :  -20 
 -10    5   45   10  -15 avg :    7 
  -2   -4  -52   19   15
```

---

## old: Numpy

You can use NumPy

```
data = [[1, -20, -100, 50, 60],
        [3, 4, -100, -3, 0],
        [-10, 5, 45, 10, -15]]

import numpy as np

colMean = np.floor(np.mean(data,0)).astype(int).tolist()
rowMean = np.floor(np.mean(data,1)).astype(int).tolist()
```

I used `np.floor()` as from your example it seems you want to round down.

Comment: Actually, there are many methods to solve this. Thus, there is no single best answer to such a question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, using numpy just for ease and beacuse it allows to make more complex computations, but you can substitute it with your formula.

```
import numpy as np

with open('number.txt','r') as file1:
    file2 = open('text2.txt','w')
    line = file1.readlines()
    for i in range(len(line)):
        #print(line )
        a = str(line[i]).replace('\n','')
        b = [int(n.replace('\\n','')) for n in a.split()]
        text = a+' avg: '+ str( np.mean(b) ) + ' \n '
        file2.write( text )
file2.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The newline character was removed from the set as it will generate an error.

> ```
> 1 -20 -100 50 60  
> 3 4 -100 -3  
> -10 5 45 10 -15
> ```

```
with open('number.txt','r') as file1:
    file2 = open('text2.txt','w')
    line = file1.readlines()

    for s in line:
        # get the individual data and make them floating-point
        data = map(float, s.split()) 

        # doing stuffs with the data
        print(sum(data) / len(data))
```

Updated my answer after @SpghttCd comment. You should now be able to access the columns.

```
with open('number.txt','r') as file1:
    file2 = open('text2.txt','w')

    # recreating the matrix get the individual data and make them floating-points
    m = list([map(float, s.split()) for s in file1.readlines()])

    # calculations in lines
    print(sum(m[0]) / len(m[0]))
    print(sum(m[1]) / len(m[1]))
    print(sum(m[2]) / len(m[2]))

    # calculations in columns
    c = [l[0] for l in m]
    print(sum(c) / len(c))

    # or in a way more like what you tried
    tmp = 0
    for j in range(len(m)): # accessing the first columns of each line of the matrix
        tmp += int(m[j][0]) / len(m[j])
    print(tmp)
```

Comment: IMO your solution lacks the mean over columns

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(r"G:\python1.txt","r") as f1:
   with open(r"G:\output.txt","w") as f2:
    l=f1.readlines()
    for li in l:
        li=li.replace("\n","")
        temp=li.split(" ")
        sum=0
        for x in temp:
            avg=0
            sum=sum+int(x)
        avg=sum/len(temp)
        temp1=str(round(avg))
        l1=str(li)
        print("l1",l1)
        f2.write(l1+" "+ "avg:"+temp1)
        f2.write("\n")
```

Comment: You should provide a short explanation to your answer

Comment: I think you forgot columm`s average